# Win32 API AnimateWindow Freezes WinForm

Tags: vb.net, winforms, winapi

I am calling the native Win32 API in a WinForm.

Before I explain further I should explain what I am trying to do. I am making an API call to retrieve some data and then display that on a WinForm. However I am trying to replicate a native Toast Notification (but note that this is a desktop exe @ the moment).

I am able to retrieve data and show it on the form via AnimateWindow.

However I need to *show the form for 5 seconds*. I've used **Thread.Sleep(5000)** and I know that this isn't the correct way to show the form.

I also need to have a close button on the form (with no form-border visible) just a "X" png in a PictureBox. So I was hoping on the PictureBox click event I would be able to close the form.

BUT, Since I've used **Thread.Sleep(5000)** I am unable to click the form! Even when I hover over the form the cursor just switches to the waiting cursor.

Is there any way I can accomplish that close button?

I will post code if need be.

Comment: Use a timer. In Win32 `SetTimer` is the API function.

Comment: @JonathanPotter would that make my Form responsive so I can click on the "X" image?

Comment: Yes, you just create a timer and then continue as normal. When the timer goes off you get a message.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the form responsive during the pause using Async/Await with Task.Delay():

```
Private Async Sub AnimateWindowSub()

    ' ... { animate window call here } ...

    Await Task.Delay(5000)
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub pb_X_Close_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles pb_X_Close.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

The Async/Await combo allows the message pump to still work and trap the PictureBox click event, despite the pause, and close.